# WPF Check box: Check changed handling

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

In WPF data binding, I can bind the IsChecked property to some data, e.g. user setting, but I need to handle "CheckChanged" event, I know I can seperately handle ***Checked***, ***Unchecked*** event, but is there any way to get notified when this value is changed?

```
<CheckBox Content="Case Sensitive" IsChecked="{Binding bSearchCaseSensitive,
          Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}}" />
```

Note: I don't care if it is checked or unchecked. I just want to be notified when it is changed.

Comment: What do you want that for? why don't you bind the `IsChecked` property to something in the ViewModel and react to that property? UI is not Data.

Comment: It is already bound to user setting. UI is not data, is this related to the question raised?

Comment: My point is that if the ViewModel needs to be aware when that changes, you should really bind that to the ViewModel, and not to a static thing, then from within the VM you could change the static value.

Comment: I don't want to change the value, I want to handle the changed event and do sth else, for instance, a message box is shown. Do you have any suggestions to hook this event?

Comment: Noted with thanks. But I am trying to see if there can be even concise solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26387/discussion-between-david-and-highcore)

Answer (score 122):

That you *can* handle the checked and unchecked events seperately doesn't mean you *have to*. If you don't want to follow the MVVM pattern you can simply attach the same handler to both events and you have your change signal:

```
<CheckBox Checked="CheckBoxChanged" Unchecked="CheckBoxChanged"/>
```

and in Code-behind;

```
private void CheckBoxChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Eureka, it changed!");
}
```

Please note that WPF strongly encourages the MVVM pattern utilizing INotifyPropertyChanged and/or DependencyProperties for a reason. This is something that works, not something I would like to encourage as good programming habit.

Answer (score 38):

As a checkbox click = a checkbox change the following will also work:

```xml
<CheckBox Click="CheckBox_Click" />
```

```cs
private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // ... do some stuff
}
```

It has the additional advantage of working when `IsThreeState="True"` whereas just handling Checked and Unchecked does not.

Comment: What happens if Checkbox if disabled but you click it? I guess the event still fires, which is not the desired behaviour, most of the times

Comment: That shouldn't happen. If it's disabled, click event will also be disabled.

Comment: It does have the correct behavior for disabled controls and when the keyboard is used. The significant difference between this and a general "state change" event is that the event doesn't fire when the checkbox is changed programmatically.

Answer (score 15):

Im putting this in an answer because it's too long for a comment:

If you need the VM to be aware when the `CheckBox` is changed, you should really bind the `CheckBox` to the VM, and not a static value:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private bool _caseSensitive;
    public bool CaseSensitive
    {
        get { return _caseSensitive; }
        set
        {
            _caseSensitive = value;
            NotifyPropertyChange(() => CaseSensitive);

            Settings.Default.bSearchCaseSensitive = value;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<CheckBox Content="Case Sensitive" IsChecked="{Binding CaseSensitive}"/>
```

Comment: @HighScore, Thanks, this is a solution, but overkill for my case. I don't want to resort to INotifyPropertyChanged, it is too cumbersome. :)

Comment: @David What? how are you handling WPF two-way binding without `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Also, that's got nothing to do with the example, it's just there because it's a ViewModel property. My example works just fine if you remove that.

Comment: It is true, this is two way binding. the setting can be both read and written, with a pity that I am not notified of the setter change.

Comment: @RalfdeKleine, I don't know what is the point of your comment, as is already pointed out by others.

Comment: @RalfdeKleine, I never state that.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old question, but how about just binding to `Command` if using MVVM?

ex:

```
<CheckBox Content="Case Sensitive" Command="{Binding bSearchCaseSensitive}"/>
```

For me it triggers on both `Check` and `Uncheck`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple and proper way I've found to Handle Checked/Unchecked events using MVVM pattern is the Following, with Caliburn.Micro :

```
 <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedBooleanProperty}" Content="{DynamicResource DisplayContent}" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Checked] = [Action CheckBoxClicked()]; [Event Unchecked] = [Action CheckBoxClicked()]" />
```

And implement a Method CheckBoxClicked() in the ViewModel, to do stuff you want.

Answer (score 0):

What about the [Checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.checked.aspx) event? Combine that with [AttachedCommandBehaviors](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) or something similar, and a [DelegateCommand](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html) to get a function fired in your viewmodel everytime that event is called.

Comment: As commented in the question, I don't want to use Checked/Unchecked event handler, what I cared is the "changed" signal.