# CheckBox does not react to unchecking

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I have 3 CheckBoxes and I want to disable/enable two of them when the other one is checked/unchecked. The first step works (if I check `checkBoxcaja`, the other two checkBoxes are disabled well, but when I uncheck `checkBoxcaja`, the other two checkBoxes don't return to their original Enabled state.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm a newbie in WPF.

This is the code:

```
private void checkBoxcaja_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBoxcaja.IsChecked == true)
    {
        checkBoxbanderola.IsEnabled = false;
        checkBoxletra.IsEnabled = false;
    }
    else if (checkBoxcaja.IsChecked == false)
    {
        checkBoxbanderola.IsEnabled = true;
        checkBoxletra.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: One thing you could have tried is setting a breakpoint inside the event to see what was happening - the first thing you may have noticed was that the breakpoint was only ever hit when the box was checked. That may have given a clue as to direction to start looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking a guess here and say you connected this to the `Checked` event.

Well, that's only fired if the box is *checked*. There is an `Unchecked` event that is fired when it is *unchecked* so you need to connect to that as well. Half you method belongs there.

```
private void checkBoxcaja_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    checkBoxbanderola.IsEnabled = false;
    checkBoxletra.IsEnabled = false;
}

private void checkBoxcaja_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    checkBoxbanderola.IsEnabled = true;
    checkBoxletra.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Don't forget to hook them up. Alternatively, [you can use the same event handler for both.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15481658/2060725)

Comment: If you use the same event handler for both, you can simply do: "checkBoxbanderola.IsEnabled = !checkBoxcaja.IsChecked" etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this completely in XAML with Datatriggers:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="CBOne" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Content="One" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></CheckBox>
<CheckBox x:Name="CBTwo" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Content="Two" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <CheckBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CBOne, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CBOne, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
<CheckBox x:Name="CBThree" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Content="Three" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <CheckBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CBOne, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CBOne, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```